LTspice phase margin inconsistencies
I am doing some tests on phase margin measurement using LTSpice.
My circuit is a linear voltage regulator (24V to 5V):

The 2.5V reference (Vref) set the 5V output.
The aim of my tests is compare the loop phase margin measurement with the "indirect" methods: the overshoot of the small step response and closed loop AC peaking measurement.
Vref superimposes also a 10mV step, to get the Vout overshoot.
The compensation stage implements a type 2 network, with a phase margin of 60° at fc = 10kHz. I have verified this "opening the loop" in this way:

V1 performs the AC sweep and I get the following open loop response measuring Vout:

So, the 60° phase margin at 10kHz is confirmed.
But, if I superimpose the 10mV step on Vref (to the orginal circuit) I get this overshoot on Vout:

The % overshoot is 100*8.32mV/20mV = 41.6%   that is typical of a 30° phase margin, quite different from the 60° of open loop measurement!

Now if I consider the closed loop gain peaking I have 3.8dB:

This value is typical of a 37° phase margin, quite different from the 60° of open loop measurement!

Step response and AC peaking shows a phase margin quite close, but the true open loop phase margin measurement is very different.
Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
******************************************  Edit  Oct 23, 2024 **************************************
According to @LvW suggestion I have performed the open loop PM measurement opening the loop at the output of opamp by means of V1, a 0V DC/1V AC voltage source:

The open loop now should become Vc/Vx. The measured PM is still 60°:


The graph "Phase margin vs. peaking" is valid for a second-order response only. More than that, the loop gain simulation arrangement is not correct. You have broken the loop at a high-resistive node which requires load mirrorring.

Thank you for your comment. I agree with you that these relationships are a good approximation only if the system can be approximated by a second order. As regards opening the loop, can you show me how should I perform that? I have also tried breaking the loop after the opamp but open loop phase margin is the same, so it seems quite invariant to me. Moreover, repeating all these steps with another simulator (TINA-TI) I obtain an overshoot around 10%, that perfectly agrees with a phase margin of 60°.

@ Massimo Why not open the loop directly at the opamp output? In this case it would be sufficient to place the test ac voltage source BETWEEN the opamp output and R7 (simplified Middlebrook method). No large inductor and no large cap would be necessary.

Thank you @LvW, I really appreciate your help. I have edited the post with your suggestion, but the measurement seems to confirm the same PM as before.

Note that the 2N3906 is not able to withstand the power needed ... to be verified.

@ Massimo - OK, I have overlooked the role of R3 and Rload. Both resistors make the output resistance at the collector of Q2 unexpected and extremely low.  Really 10 milliOhms in parallel with 3 Ohms? In this case, the loop can be opened without causing any loading error.


Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

I don't think you are doing anything wrong except assuming that the initial peak in the transient response is indicative of phase margin...
The initial overshoot is only marginally affected by phase margin. If you want to examine how phase margin and percentage overshoot are better related to each other I draw your attention to this graph supplied by Verbal Kint in his answer to this question: Intuitive understanding of relation between phase margin and peak overshoot and/or damping factor: -


Thank you for your comment. I think that my case is a little different, since the graph that you show here should be the Vout drop (and settling) in case of a load step (and it is true that the first drop marginally depends on PM, since it is related to fc and Cout). In my case, the step is applied on Vref. So an input step must correspond to a Vout step plus some oscillations related to PM (in case the closed loop system can be approximated with a second order model as in the majority of cases).

Made with microcap v12.
No need to cut anywhere, just insert the "right" symbol at the "right" place.
Here is my "stability" simulation.
Note that "powers" are a "little" high for the 2N3906 and 2N2222 BJT's ...

here is also the TRAN Analysis with some C1 "variations".

